# Sublime Text 2 regex matching with backreference

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, multiline, backreference

I have a multi-line string

> Some test
> String
> Here

I am using this regex pattern to find it `(Some\s.*)(.|\n)*` & replace it with `\1\2`

Instead of getting the same text back, I get

> Some test e

Why isn't the second backreference working? Is there a better way to specify multiline in regex rather than `(.|\n)*`

PS : Using Sublime Text 2 on Windows

**Update :** I see my mistake after reading Jerry's answer.

Comment: Windows == `\r\n` | Linux == `\n`

Comment: You can use ^ as start of line and $ as end of line. Maybe you have to set a flag in the regex engine

Comment: @HamZa : Selecting isn't the problem, My file has `\n` only - unix style. It's the replacement that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.|\n)*
```

In this captured group, you'll get only the last match. You could try using this instead:

```
((?:.|\n)*)
```

Or if you want to match everything you could possibly use something like:

```
([\s\S]*)
```

Comment: @buffer I can't seem to find a reference :( [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) used to have a page describing it... But you can play around and see for yourself. Here's a [demo site](http://regex101.com/r/aL5wW5). I already put an example there and you can see the matched group is `d`, i.e. the last matched character.

Comment: Took a moment to realize my obvious mistake after looking at your answer. Thanks.